# How to paste yanked text into the Vim command line

Tags: vim, copy-paste

I'd like to paste yanked text into Vim's command line. Is it possible?

Comment: For a special case of executing the yanked text directly, see: [How do you run a vim command that is the text inside a buffer? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1018808/how-do-you-run-a-vim-command-that-is-the-text-inside-a-buffer).

Answer (score 1346, accepted):

Yes. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> then <kbd>"</kbd>. If you have literal control characters in what you have yanked, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd>, <kbd>"</kbd>.

Here is an explanation of what you can do with registers. What you can do with registers is extraordinary, and once you know how to use them you cannot live without them.

Registers are basically storage locations for strings. Vim has many registers that work in different ways:

- `0` (yank register: when you use `y` in normal mode, without specifying a register, yanked text goes there and also to the default register),
- `1` to `9` (shifting delete registers, when you use commands such as `c` or `d`, what has been deleted goes to register 1, what was in register 1 goes to register 2, *etc.*),
- `"` (default register, also known as unnamed register. This is where the <kbd>"</kbd> comes in <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>"</kbd>),
- `a` to `z` for your own use (capitalized `A` to `Z` are for appending to corresponding registers).
- `_` (acts like `/dev/null` (Unix) or `NUL` (Windows), you can write to it but it's discarded and when you read from it, it is always empty),
- `-` (small delete register),
- `/` (search pattern register, updated when you look for text with `/`, `?`, `*` or `#` for instance; you can also write to it to dynamically change the search pattern),
- `:` (stores last VimL typed command via `Q` or `:`, readonly),
- `+` and `*` (system clipboard registers, you can write to them to set the clipboard and read the clipboard contents from them)

See `:help registers` for the full reference.

You can, at any moment, use `:registers` to display the contents of all registers. Synonyms and shorthands for this command are `:display`, `:reg` and `:di`.

In Insert or Command-line mode, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> plus a register name, inserts the contents of this register. If you want to insert them literally (no auto-indenting, no conversion of control characters like `0x08` to backspace, etc), you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd>, register name.
See `:help i_CTRL-R` and following paragraphs for more reference.

But you can also do the following (and I probably forgot many uses for registers).

- In normal mode, hit <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>:</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>. The last command you used in vim is pasted into your buffer.
  Let's decompose: `"` is a Normal mode command that lets you select what register is to be used during the next yank, delete or paste operation. So <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>:</kbd> selects the colon register (storing last command). Then <kbd>p</kbd> is a command you already know, it pastes the contents of the register.

  cf. `:help "`, `:help quote_:`
- You're editing a VimL file (for instance your `.vimrc`) and would like to execute a couple of consecutive lines right now: <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>:</kbd><kbd>@</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.
  Here, <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> yanks current and next line (this is because j is a linewise motion but this is out of scope of this answer) into the default register (also known as the unnamed register). Then the `:@` Ex command plays Ex commands stored in the register given as argument, and `"` is how you refer to the unnamed register. Also see the top of this answer, which is related.

  Do not confuse `"` used here (which is a register name) with the `"` from the previous example, which was a Normal-mode command.

  cf. `:help :@` and `:help quote_quote`
- Insert the last search pattern into your file in Insert mode, or into the command line, with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>/</kbd>.

  cf. `:help quote_/`, `help i_CTRL-R`

  Corollary: Keep your search pattern but add an alternative: `/` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>/</kbd> `\|alternative`.
- You've selected two words in the middle of a line in visual mode, yanked them with `y`, they are in the unnamed register. Now you want to open a new line just below where you are, with those two words: `:pu`. This is shorthand for `:put "`. The `:put` command, like many Ex commands, works only linewise.

  cf. `:help :put`

  You could also have done: `:call setreg('"', @", 'V')` then `p`. The `setreg` function sets the register of which the name is given as first argument (as a string), initializes it with the contents of the second argument (and you can use registers as variables with the name `@x` where `x` is the register name in VimL), and turns it into the mode specified in the third argument, `V` for linewise, nothing for characterwise and literal `^V` for blockwise.

  cf. `:help setreg()`. The reverse functions are `getreg()` and `getregtype()`.
- If you have recorded a macro with `qa`...`q`, then `:echo @a` will tell you what you have typed, and `@a` will replay the macro (probably you knew that one, very useful in order to avoid repetitive tasks)

  cf. `:help q`, `help @`

  Corollary from the previous example: If you have `8go` in the clipboard, then `@+` will play the clipboard contents as a macro, and thus go to the 8th byte of your file. Actually this will work with almost every register. If your last inserted string was `dd` in Insert mode, then `@.` will (because the `.` register contains the last inserted string) delete a line. (Vim documentation is wrong in this regard, since it states that the registers `#`, `%`, `:` and `.` will only work with `p`, `P`, `:put` and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>).

  cf. `:help @`

  Don't confuse `:@` (command that plays Vim commands from a register) and `@` (normal-mode command that plays normal-mode commands from a register).

  Notable exception is `@:`. The command register does not contain the initial colon neither does it contain the final carriage return. However in Normal mode, `@:` will do what you expect, interpreting the register as an Ex command, not trying to play it in Normal mode. So if your last command was `:e`, the register contains `e` but `@:` will reload the file, not go to end of word.

  cf. `:help @:`
- Show what you will be doing in Normal mode before running it: `@='dd'` <kbd>Enter</kbd>. As soon as you hit the `=` key, Vim switches to expression evaluation: as you enter an expression and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, Vim computes it, and the result acts as a register content. Of course the register `=` is read-only, and one-shot. Each time you start using it, you will have to enter a new expression.

  cf. `:help quote_=`

  Corollary: If you are editing a command, and you realize that you should need to insert into your command line some line from your current buffer: don't press <kbd>Esc</kbd>! Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> `=getline(58)` <kbd>Enter</kbd>. After that you will be back to command line editing, but it has inserted the contents of the 58th line.
- Define a search pattern manually: `:let @/ = 'foo'`

  cf. `:help :let`

  Note that doing that, you needn't to escape `/` in the pattern. However you need to double all single quotes of course.
- Copy all lines beginning with `foo`, and afterwards all lines containing `bar` to clipboard, chain these commands: `qaq` (resets the *a* register storing an empty macro inside it), `:g/^foo/y A`, `:g/bar/y A`, `:let @+ = @a`.

  Using a capital register name makes the register work in append mode

  Better, if `Q` has not been remapped by `mswin.vim`, start Ex mode with `Q`, chain those “colon commands” which are actually better called “Ex commands”, and go back to Normal mode by typing `visual`.

  cf. `:help :g`, `:help :y`, `:help Q`
- Double-space your file: `:g/^/put _`. This puts the contents of the black hole register (empty when reading, but writable, behaving like `/dev/null`) linewise, after each line (because every line has a beginning!).
- Add a line containing `foo` before each line: `:g/^/-put ='foo'`. This is a clever use of the expression register. Here, `-` is a synonym for `.-1` (cf. `:help :range`). Since `:put` puts the text after the line, you have to explicitly tell it to act on the previous one.
- Copy the entire buffer to the system clipboard: `:%y+`.

  cf. `:help :range` (for the `%` part) and `:help :y`.
- If you have misrecorded a macro, you can type `:let @a='` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> `=replace(@a,"'","''",'g')` <kbd>Enter</kbd> `'` and edit it. This will modify the contents of the macro stored in register `a`, and it's shown here how you can use the expression register to do that. Another, simpler, way of modifying a macro is to paste it in a buffer (`"ap`), edit it, and put it again into the register, by selecting it and `"ay`.
- If you did `dddd`, you might do `uu` in order to undo. With `p` you could get the last deleted line. But actually you can also recover up to 9 deletes with the registers `@1` through `@9`.

  Even better, if you do `"1P`, then `.` in Normal mode will play `"2P`, and so on.

  cf. `:help .` and `:help quote_number`
- If you want to insert the current date in Insert mode: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>`=strftime('%y%m%d')`<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

  cf. `:help strftime()`

Once again, what can be confusing:

- `:@` is a command-line command that interprets the contents of a register as vimscript and sources it
- `@`  in normal mode command that interprets the contents of a register as normal-mode keystrokes (except when you use `:` register, that contains last played command without the initial colon: in this case it replays the command as if you also re-typed the colon and the final return key).
- `"`  in normal mode command that helps you select a register for yank, paste, delete, correct, etc.
- `"`  is also a valid register name (the default, or unnamed, register) and therefore can be passed as an arguments for commands that expect register names

Comment: @Benoit - It looks pretty good this way; I don't quite remember the way it was before. I read this a while ago, and I wrote my comment because I realized that I had already changed the way I used vim because of reading your answer a while back.

Comment: For a better understanding read the 42 pdf in this url http://zmievski.org/talks/

Comment: Shouldn't `:g/^foo/y a` be `:g/^foo/y A` to copy more than just the last line matching foo? (And then you may want to prepend `let @a = @_` to clear the register.) Or am I missing something with the way you'd chain these commands? I assume that means to enter them one after the other if not using Ex mode. Even using Ex mode (with `Q`), typing them in one after the other doesn't work.

Comment: @pydave: You're right. Clearing the register can also be done with `qaq`.

Comment: Dont forget :reg which will list all registers along with their content

Comment: In recent versions of vim, deletions that are smaller than one line go in to the "small deletions register" instead of going in to the numbered registers. References: [Vi and Vim](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4532/numbered-register-doesnt-record-most-deleted-text-within-a-line), [Vi and Vim](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2493/can-i-make-vim-also-save-small-deletions-into-register-1), [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/yyq4a/is_there_anyway_to_configure_vim_to_use_the/)

Comment: There is also a very useful `.` register. Great write up though.

Comment: Regarding shifting delete registers, do not forget this uh, design decision: `:help "1` - Numbered register 1 contains the text deleted by the most recent delete or change command, unless the command specified another register _or the text is less than one line_ (the small delete register is used then).

Comment: Also note that you still have to enter the command line using `:` before doing the CTRL+R command

Comment: Is there a way to escape regex special characters similar to `C-O`?

Comment: I often come here looking to paste yanked text into the vim _terminal_, only to invoke bash reverse-i-search. Spend a few minutes trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Only then realizing it's a question for the vim _command line_. I wish google would stop sending me here and that'd someday remember how to do this 

spoiler, it's `CTRL-W ""`

Comment: Back again. See `:help t_CTRL-W_quote`

Answer (score 58):

For pasting something that is the system clipboard you can just use <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> - <kbd>INS</kbd>.

It works in Windows, but I am guessing it works well in Linux too.

Comment: Yup, works in Linux too. Tested under GNOME in both Vim and GVim.

Comment: This actually feeds the pasteboard to Vim as keyboard input, so if you're in normal mode and paste `:!rm -rf /<cr>`, it'd execute that. Use registers instead!

Comment: @lericson Didn't I say in my answer that this useful for something that is in the system keyboard? I don't understand the downvote. And for you example, seriously? You really have that in the clipboard? And you don't think that typing `shift-ins` is easier than `ctrl-R+*`? This is of course if you are in gvim. If you are in the terminal connected to another machine and you want to paste something from your clipboard do you know something better than `shift-ins`? because the registers don't work in that situation. Please think before you comment and do other things (like downvoting).

Comment: I think it is misinformation and I have acted on that judgement.

Comment: Did you actually read and understand the part that you may not be able to paste using the registers and then this would be a good option? This question complements the accepted answer.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I just get '<S-Insert>' added to my command line. Perhaps I'm missing something. (Ubuntu 19.04/2:8.1.0320-1ubuntu3.1).

Comment: `S-Insert` works only on certain terminal emulators. And as @lericson properly said it will literally drop content of your clipboard as if it was typed by user. Without suggesting to enter `insert` mode before pressing `S-Insert`, this answer is at least incomplete.

Comment: Thanks so much. Simple and effective.

Answer (score 43):

"I'd like to paste yanked text into Vim command line."

While the top voted answer is very complete, I prefer editing the command history.

In normal mode, type: `q:`. This will give you a list of recent commands, editable and searchable with normal vim commands. You'll start on a blank command line at the bottom.

For the exact thing that the article asks, pasting a yanked line (or yanked anything) into a command line, yank your text and then: `q:p` (get into command history edit mode, and then (p)ut your yanked text into a new command line. Edit at will, <kbd>enter</kbd> to execute.

To get out of command history mode, it's the opposite. In normal mode in command history, type: `:q` + <kbd>enter</kbd>

Comment: if you are already modifying an existing command and did not press 'q:' press ctrl+f and it'll pull up the ability to edit the command history.

Answer (score 23):

For pasting something from the system clipboard into the Vim command line ("command mode"), use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> followed by <kbd>+</kbd>. For me, at least on Ubuntu, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd> is not working.

PS: I am not sure why <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> followed by <kbd>*</kbd>, which is theoretically the same as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> followed by <kbd>+</kbd> doesn't seem to work always. I searched and discovered the <kbd>+</kbd> version and it seems to work always, at least on my box.

Comment: The difference between  Ctrl-r+ and Ctrl-r* is that the former is the regular clipboard, but in Linux there is a second type of clipboard called "primary" that represents the most recently selected text  (the middle button mouse paste from it). This is not available in Windows or MAC though

Answer (score 13):

It's worth noting also that the yank registers are the same as the macro buffers. In other words, you can simply write out your whole command in your document (including your pasted snippet), then `"by` to yank it to the `b` register, and then run it with `@b`.

Answer (score 4):

For context, this information comes from out-of-the-box, no plugins, no .vimrc Vim 7.4 behavior in Linux Mint with the default options.

You can always select text with the mouse (or using <kbd>V</kbd> or <kbd>v</kbd> and placing the selection in the "* register), and paste it into the command line with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>.

Typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> in the command line will cause a prompt for a register name. so typing <kbd>:CTRL-r*</kbd> will place the content register * into the command line. It will paste any register, not just "*. See `:help c_CTRL-R`.

Furthermore, the middle mouse button will paste into the command line.

See `:help->quote-plus` for a description of the how X Window deals with selection. Even in a plain, out-of-the-box Vim (again, in Vim 7.4 in Linux Mint, anyway), any selection made with the left mouse button can be pasted in the command line with the middle mouse button.

In addition, the middle mouse button will also paste text selected in Vim into many other X Window  applications, even GUI ones (for example, Firefox and [Thunderbird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Thunderbird)) and pasting text into the command line is also possible where the text was selected from other apps.

See :help->x11-selection for addl information.

**tl;dr**

Try the :CTRL-r approach first, and then use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> or the middle mouse button if you need something else.

It is conceded that it can be confusing.

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar problem.  I wanted the selected text to end up in a command, but not rely on pasting it in.  Here's the command I was trying to write a mapping for:

```
:call VimuxRunCommand("python")
```

The docs for this plugin only show using string literals. The following will break if you try to select text that contains doublequotes:

```
vnoremap y:call VimuxRunCommand("<c-r>"")<cr>
```

To get around this, you just reference the contents of the macro using `@` :

```
vnoremap y:call VimuxRunCommand(@")<cr>
```

Passes the contents of the unnamed register in and works with my double quote and multiline edgecases.

Comment: I think your last example is missing a ".  Perhaps you meant VimuxRunCommand("@").

Comment: That would send the `@` character to the vimux command.  think of `@` as escaping the following double quote and it being treated as a register instead of as a regular character.  The `vnoremap` i've defined is active in visual mode, so it yanks the selected text, and then pastes it into the vimux command, sending it to a running interpreter  in an adjacent pane.
really great for working on a script and testing small portions of it with a couple keystrokes.

Answer (score 2):

**OS X**

If you are using Vim in Mac OS X, unfortunately it comes with older version, and not complied with clipboard options. Luckily, [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_%28package_management_software%29) can easily solve this problem.

Install Vim:

`brew install vim --with-lua --with-override-system-vi`

Install the GUI version of Vim:

`brew install macvim --with-lua --with-override-system-vi`

Restart the terminal for it to take effect.

Append the following line to `~/.vimrc`

`set clipboard=unnamed`

Now you can copy the line in Vim with `yy` and paste it system-wide.

Answer (score 2):

1. `"[a-z]y`: Copy text to the [a-z] register
2. Use `:!` to go to the edit command
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>: Follow the register identity to paste what you copy.

It used to CentOS 7.

Comment: What is meant by *"It used to CentOS 7."*?

Answer (score 1):

If you have two values yanked into two different registers (for example register `a` and register `b`) then you can simply set a variable `c` and do the operation on it.

For example, `:set c = str2float(@a) + str2float(@b)` and then you can paste the content of `c` anywhere.

For example whilst in INSERT mode, `CTRL + R` then type `=` to enter into the expression register and just type `c` after equal sign and hit ENTER. Done you should now have the total of `a` and `b` registers.

All these can be recorded in a macro and repeated over!

The `str2float` function is used if you are working with floats, if you don't, you will get integers instead.

I am not sure if this is idiomatic but it worked for my case where I needed to add 2 numbers in a row and repeat it for 500 more lines.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use Control-v to paste from the system clipboard, so I use:

```
cnoremap <C-v> <C-r>+
```

Answer (score 0):

yang's answer worked for me.

1. Select the lines in visual mode. Press Shift-V to select lines.
2. Press " + [a-z] + y (three keys)
3. Press : to go to the command line
4. Press Ctrl-R
5. Press [a-z]