# VIM: how to replace a word

Tags: vim, replace

I guess, the problem is pretty common. Let's say, we have a source file and wish to replace some string with another string.

Usually, I use the following command:

```
:%s/test/testValue/gc
```

But, what if the string is pretty long and we need just to touch it up? It is boring to type something like that:

```
%s/someLongAndDirtyString/somelongAndDirtystring/gc
```

Is it possible to place a cursor on `someLongAndDirtyString` word, press some magic key and get the following in the last line?

```
%s/someLongAndDirtyString/someLongAndDirtyString/gc
```

Then we may change the new string a bit and proceed with replacing.

Sure, it is just an idea. Please, provide me with the best way of doing such replacements.

Thanks

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You might be interested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997078/how-do-you-paste-text-into-a-vim-colon-command/3997110#3997110) I gave on how to use registers, but here are four methods to do that:

### Method 1

While editing a command, hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> then <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> to insert word under the cursor.

Also see `:help c_CTRL-R`

### Method 2

Go to your word, hit <kbd>*</kbd>, and do `:%s//replacement/g`. When no search pattern is used, last search pattern, taken from register `@/`, is used.

### Method 3 (you will probably like that one)

Do a `:nnoremap <f12> :%s/<c-r><c-w>/<c-r><c-w>/gc<c-f>$F/i` (ctrl-f is determined by the 'cedit' option)

You can put this mapping into your .vimrc.
This will map the <kbd>F12</kbd> key to what you want, and your cursor will be left where you want.

### Method 4

Go to your word, hit <kbd>*</kbd>, and do `:%s//`<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>,<kbd>/</kbd>`/gc`
CTRL-R then / inserts contents of your search register.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I won't be surprised if there is a way to do in-place replacing (as in snippets :-) It would be really cool!

Comment: If you want to have on-the-fly correction of common errors, see `:help :iabbrev` or `:help abbreviations`

Answer (score 14):

Well, if your cursor is on the word you want to replace, you can hit * which will highlight and search for the word, and then you can type:

```
:%s//newstring/gc
```

and vim will insert the last searched string in between the slashes.