# Vim In-File Commands

Tags: vim

I'm after a means by which I can add additional commands to a text file via vim.  For example, just as you can do something like this:

```
# vim:syntax=foo
```

I'd like to do something like:

```
# vim:option call matchadd('Special', '\(REQUIRED\|OPTIONAL\)')
```

Any ideas?  I know I can write a syntax file, but this is not what I'm after for now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vim modeline syntax (see `:help modeline`) is not intended to specify commands
to execute during file opening.  That is exactly what autocommands is for (see
`:help autocommand`).  What you are trying to do should be an autocommand
similar the following.

```
autocmd FileType foo call matchadd('Special', '\(REQUIRED\|OPTIONAL\)')
```

or

```
autocmd BufReadPost *.foo call matchadd('Special', '\(REQUIRED\|OPTIONAL\)')
```

(Here instead of `*.foo` you can use any pattern that matches path or filename
(or both) of the target file.)

If the configuration you are setting up is local to some files or a project,
and you don't want to pollute your `.vimrc` with those `autocmd`s, use
[localvimrc](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=441) plugin.  It allows you to have a "local" `.vimrc` file next to
your target file or project folder.  Script stored in that `.lvimrc` is
executed when you open files in the same directory where the "local" `.vimrc`
is, or in its subdirectories.  Autocommands shown above (or any other
configurations) can be stored in a `.lvimrc` file local the project.  For
details about [localvimrc](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=441) configuration see the homepage of the plugin.

Comment: So it's not possible, but that's okay, I've just now added a .vim/ syntax file; and your comments are nevertheless very useful - thank you :)

Comment: ftplugins are generally going to be better than autocommand FileType lines.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer to your question, but I have also searched for Truth, and this question here is the closest one to it:

[Vim: How to execute selected text as vim commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268532/vim-how-to-execute-selected-text-as-vim-commands)

It isn't automatic, but potentially only one keypress away it's close enough. :)

Answer (score 0):

My [ModelineCommands plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=5767) extends Vim's built-in modelines to execute any Ex command(s) when a file is opened. A set of configurable validators examine the commands and can verify the correctness of an optional command digest, in order to prevent the execution of potentially malicious commands from unknown sources. (That's the main reason why Vim doesn't offer this feature!) This way, you could restrict the commands to only simple `:let`, or have the plugin query you to confirm execution of anything that isn't signed with your own secret key.