# How to save Vim commands into a specific buffer and reuse them again

Tags: vim

I need to do lots of search and replace commands, and I might re-use these commands soon. I know I could use `q:` to select the previous commands but there are some other dummy commands inside and I need to search the wanted commands again.  That's not efficient.

Are there ways or plugins that I could save those frequently-used commands into a specific buffer and I can choose one of them quickly?

Comment: Using vim "recording" could be an alternative way to do this. However, it better shows the full list of each recording command and I can choose them fast.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vim: How to execute selected text as vim commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268532/vim-how-to-execute-selected-text-as-vim-commands)

Comment: Generally thats what mappings/registers are for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a fair job for a whole plugin, as Vim does not track commmands' "frequency usage".

However, you can make some sort of a "poor man" solution instantly:

1. Create a temporary buffer (or use some sort of a "scratch" plugin).
2. Whenever a "useful" command was issued, go to your "scratch" buffer and add the content of a register `:` into it. For example, <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>:</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>.
3. To execute a "useful" command you'll need a mapping:

   ```
   nnoremap <buffer><CR> 0y$<C-W>p:<C-R>0
   ```

   I.e.: copy current line; switch to previous window; open cmdline and put yanked text there.

Now go to your "scratch" buffer and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to compose a command-line.

To develop this stuff into "production-ready" form consider the following changes:

1. Design some sort of cool UI instead (buffer-based or popup-based).
2. Trap `CmdlineLeave` to automate command list tracking.
3. Add buffer-mappings automatically.