# Vim: LaTeX-suite table of contents

Tags: vim, latex-suite

maybe I'm drastically overlooking something trivial, but is there any possibility in Vim (with LaTeX-suite) to view the table of contents?

To be more precisely, I'm looking for something equivalent to emacs'/AucTeX' `C-c =`, which displays a nice readable  table of contents in a separate buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe use:

```
:let @a=''
:g/\\\(part\|chapter\|section\|subsection\|subsubsection\|paragraph\|subparagraph\)\>/y A
:winc n
:put a
```

maybe have a function to do that and map whatever you like to that.

Comment: Now can you make that nested and linkable ;-)

Comment: @Benoit Could you please explain `\>/y`? I get the `g`: global search for ``\\`` (literal backslash) + ``\(`` (annoying vim syntax for non-literal parenthesis to get a group) and so forth. Then you save that as `A`, yet later call `put a`? Is this case-insensitive? What am I missing here?

Comment: `\>` is part of the pattern and ensures there is no other word character afterwords (equivalent to `\b` in some regexp engines). `/` is the pattern delimiter, therefore it ends the pattern. `y A` is a command that yanks the line into register a, in append mode (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997078/how-to-paste-yanked-text-into-vim-command-line/3997110#3997110 if you need to read about registers).