# How to execute the contents of a buffer?

Tags: vim

I have a vim script I'm developing in my current buffer and I want to execute it. Is there a simple way to do it?

After a long search I have only found two related ways, but not exactly what I'm looking for:

- a) "source" command - but to use it I first need to save the content to file and then "source" it back, which doesn't look simple
- b) "call" command - but I don't want to call my function, I want to execute the whole file, which defines several functions and has some code outside of functions at all

Comment: What's wrong with a)? I'd always save before executing

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use:

```
:%y"                      (alternatively: ggyG)
:@"
```

It will copy whole buffer into default register and then run it.

See `:help :y` and `:help :@` (and also `:help range` maybe).

Comment: @izhak: You are welcome. If you want to know more see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997078/how-do-you-paste-text-into-a-vim-colon-command/3997110#3997110) I made to another question.

Comment: The answer given is a complicated way to do this. The command listed as "alternate" doesn't work. See my answer on this page for a way to do it in a single, simpler command.

Comment: @jm3 Why do you say the alternate command doesn't work? It yanks the whole buffer into the " register, right?

Comment: is there anyway to create some sort of alias for this?

Answer (score 4):

An autocmd to source the file whenever you save might help:

```
autocmd BufWritePost <buffer> source %
```