# Automate running several vim commands and keystrokes

Tags: clojure, vim

I want to automate running several commands in vim, i.e. by typing `:repl`.  The commands are:

```
:ConqueTerm lein repl
<Esc>
:set syntax=clojure
<i>
```

How do I define a custom vim function (command) that executes the above?

About the above:

- `clojure` - the Clojure programming language (syntax provided by [vim-clojure-static](https://github.com/guns/vim-clojure-static)
- [`ConqueTerm`](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2771) - a vim plugin that runs a shell interactively in your vim buffer
- `lein` - [Leiningen](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen), a Clojure build tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could just create a function, and put your commands in that function:

```
fun! LeinCMD()
    execute 'ConqueTerm lein repl'
    execute 'set syntax=clojure'
    execute 'normal! i'
endf
command! Repl call LeinCMD()
```

you could source above codes, and type `:Repl` and `Enter` to test if it works for you.

**EDIT**

very nice comments by **@Zyx**. I just put them in answer, so that readers won't miss valuable information in future.

1. You need exactly no `:execute` calls here.
2. `:normal!` i is useless, to start insert mode from functions there is :startinsert and :call feedkeys(), former should be preferred. // Note: `:normal! i` “works” here because :`startinsert` is run by `:ConqueTerm`. I.e. due to the way Conque is written you don’t need `:startinsert` at all, but if it was not already there `:normal! i` would continue to do nothing useful.

Just mentioned: it would be much nicer to use `command -bar`: this way you won’t need `:execute` to chain your command with pipe symbol (try `Repl | echo "Here"` with and without -bar as a second argument to `:command`). I think it have been the default option, don’t know why Bram likes to have bad defaults in a number of places.

Comment: Thanks! For posterity, here is an answer on how to "source" the codes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326430/vim-how-to-execute-content-of-the-buffer

Comment: 1. You need exactly no `:execute` calls here. 2. `:normal! i` is useless, to start insert mode from functions there is `:startinsert` and `:call feedkeys()`, former should be preferred. // Note: `:normal! i` “works” here because `:startinsert` is run by `:ConqueTerm`. I.e. due to the way Conque is written you don’t need `:startinsert` at all, but if it was not already there `:normal! i` would continue to do nothing useful.

Comment: @ZyX I appreciate your great comment and explanation! I learned from your comment. thank you very much!

Comment: Just mentioned: it would be much nicer to use `command -bar`: this way you won’t need `:execute` to chain your command with pipe symbol (try `Repl | echo "Here"` with and without `-bar` as a second argument to `:command`). I think it have been the default option, don’t know why Bram likes to have bad defaults in a number of places.

Comment: @Zyx thank you so much. though I have ever read the `-bar`, I thought commands (no matter buildin or customer cmds) can be joined by `|` into a chain is kinda "default"....  learned from u again. btw, I updated answer and added your comments, I hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
function custom_function ()
  execute 'ConqueTerm lein repl'
  execute 'set syntax=clojure'
  return custom_function
endfunction
```

i don't know if this code will work as i have not tested it