# Extend a vim command

Tags: vim

How can I extend a command in vim?

I want to do it in two situations,

1. After a `:diffget` or `:diffput` I always want to run a `:diffupdate`
2. After a `:NERDTreeToggle` I want to run a `<C-w>=`

Comment: Do you want to _replace_ the default functionality, or create your own mapping which incorporates both functions (which is more typical)?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I don't want to have a new command, so I suppose I want to replace the default functionality, but I'm not sure about the difference between replace and map

Answer (score 3):

I am unaware of any autocmd events that would be triggered for your scenarios. However a few custom mappings might be helpful.

You can change the default `dp` and `do` mappings to also do a `:diffupdate`

```
nnoremap dp dp:diffupdate<cr>
nnoremap do do:diffupdate<cr>
```

Note there are times where you cannot use `dp` and/or `do` and must use `:diffput`/`:diffget`. In these cases I would suggest you create a commands like so:

```
command! -nargs=? -range=1 -bar Diffput <line1>,<line2>diffput <args>|diffupdate
command! -nargs=? -range=1 -bar Diffget <line1>,<line2>diffget <args>|diffupdate
```

Or you can just map `:diffupdate`

```
nnoremap <f8> :diffupdate<cr>
```

NERDTree

```
nnoremap <leader>N :NERDTreeToggle<cr><c-w>=
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can have a look to the [vim macro](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Macros). It is probably suitable for what you want to do :).

Comment: Macros are more often used for bundling editing commands. This would be more suited to a key or command mapping

Comment: To be honest, I never use macros so you are certainly true.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own custom function in VimScript in your `.vimrc` that wraps several commands.

Here's one I use to launch a Clojure Repl in a buffer using several plugins:

```
fun! LeinCMD()
    execute 'ConqueTerm lein repl'
    execute 'set syntax=clojure'
    execute 'normal! i'
endf
command! Repl call LeinCMD()
```

I then call this command with `:Repl` (note that your custom commands must always start with an uppercase letter).

Source: [Automate running several vim commands and keystrokes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15734470/automate-running-several-vim-commands-and-keystrokes)

Comment: You need exactly no `:execute` calls here.

Comment: Also note that `normal! i` is useless. For use in functions there is `startinsert`.

Comment: `:startinsert` is run by `:ConqueTerm`. Thus it *seems* `:normal! i` works, but it actually does not because scheduling entering insert mode have already been done earlier.

Comment: You can just turn the function into a two-liner `ConqueTerm lein repl` | `set syntax=clojure`. Though for such simple case I would use plain command: `command! Repl :execute 'ConqueTerm lein repl' | set syntax=clojure` (note execute is required here because usually (it is the default) user-defined commands are not defined with `-bar` thus cannot be chained this way. `ConqueTerm` is one of such usual comands).

Comment: This command is also a good candidate for `-bar`: `Repl | echo "abc"` is useless without it: complains about trailing characters instead of running `Repl` then `echo "abc"`. In fact, if I were Bram I would have made `-bar` the default.

Comment: Do you think you could put your re-write of this code in a gist?

Comment: What for? It is too small and local. Wondering why don’t you want to edit the answer, previous versions are saved in any case.

Comment: I will go back and edit my answer...when I have a free moment and fully understand you answer - BTW - if you have enough rep you can edit another user's answers.

Comment: I know. I never saw such edits except for some typo fixes thus I assume I should not do this as this is not a thing I should do.