# Vim: Set register with let that contains backslashes

Tags: vim, escaping

I want a register to contain backslashes, but when I try they get removed. Example (for
"first_name last_name" → "last_name, first name" in a file with all lines according to regex pattern:
`/^[^ \n]+ [^ \n]+$/gm`):

1. Setting register 1 with let:

   ```
   :let @1="%s/\(.*\) \(.*\)/\2, \1/g"
   ```
2. Displaying register 1 (inserted at the current line):

   ```
   :put 1
   ```
3. The insertion:

   ```
   "%s/(.*) (.*)/^B, ^A/g"
   ```

I want that register to contain backslashes so that [it can be executes as a command in command mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326430/vim-how-to-execute-the-contents-of-a-buffer).

Answer (score 0):

Fix (escape the escapes):

```
:let @1="%s/\\(.*\\) \\(.*\\)/\\2, \\1/g"
```