# Implementing CTRL+V to paste in VIM , always offset one character after pasting

Tags: vim, paste

I'm using `imap <c-v> <ESC>"+PA` in gVIM to do the pasting , however , each time i tried to paste i got unexpected result:

`aa${CURSOR}aa` , and press ^V right now , i got `a${PASTE_TXT}aaa` , but i wanted `aa${PASTE_TXT}aa`.

How can i fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `imap <c-v> <ESC>"+PA` to `imap <c-v> <ESC>"+pA`

Upper case `P` is paste before cursor position, lower case `p` is after cursor position.

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest that you do not remap CTRL-V, it is really useful when you want to insert raw characters. In order to paste in insert mode, you needn't switch to normal mode. Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd>, then <kbd>+</kbd>. That's not so long. You can remap an F-Key to do that:

```
:inoremap <F1> <C-r><C-o>+
```

or

```
:inoremap <C-v> <C-r><C-o>+
```

See `:help i_CTRL-R` for more reference. You might also like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997078/how-to-paste-text-into-vim-command-line/3997110#3997110) I gave about registers.

If you still want to keep your mapping using normal mode, replace `P` with `p` and `A` with `a`. After all you want to paste after the last character you have stopped when leaving insert mode, and to continue inserting after pasted text, not at end of line.

```
:inoremap <C-v> <Esc>"+pa
```