# Cross buffer search result list for Vim?

Tags: vim

After searching in Vim you can get a list of the search results with `:g//#` and with `:bufdo g//#` you can get list of matches in all buffers.

But using it with `bufdo` is not really realistic since it does not show the file where the match came from or give an option to jump to the match.

Is there a plugin that would allow that?

Note that I want this for the internal Vim search because I often use it via `*`, `#` and similar shortcuts. I know that [LustyExplorer](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1890) (`LustyBufferGrep`) allows to search from all buffers, but it uses its own search input... I want reuse the internal Vim search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You can paste the contents of vim search register with <kbd>CTRL-R</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997078/how-to-paste-text-into-vim-command-line/3997110#3997110). Other plug-ins that can do that include Buffersaurus.

It seems to be possible to integrate the internal Vim search to [Buffersaurus](https://github.com/jeetsukumaran/vim-buffersaurus) like this:

```
map <Leader>b :Bsgrep <c-r>/<cr>
```

Hit  <kbd>Leader</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> to open up the list.

Comment: Thanks! I added an example of possible integration to this answer.