# How to paste from buffer in ex mode of vim?

Tags: linux, vim, buffer

I am having a problem in copying certain text from a file then copying it to a new split window.
3yy|new|p

in command mode its working

as when i press

'p' in split window after copying 
its working

Comment: This question is better suitable for [http://unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @SurvivalMachine That discussion has been had: [Vim questions: do they belong to Stack Overflow or Super User?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25925/vim-questions-do-they-belong-to-stack-overflow-or-super-user) and even [on SU: Are questions about vi, vim, and other clones on-topic here?](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/309/are-questions-about-vi-vim-and-other-clones-on-topic-here/311#311). TL;DR vim is welcome as a programming tool

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I understand that you want to:

1. yank the current line and the two lines below in the current buffer,
2. open an empty buffer in a new horizontal split and
3. paste those three lines in the empty buffer.

Is that correct?

What I don't get is why you would want to do it from Ex mode while it's so easy (and working) in normal mode:

```
3yy
:new<cr>
p
```

I think that you are confusing *ex* mode, accessible with `Q` and *command* mode, accessible with `:`. You probably also confuse the `:p[rint]` command and the `:pu[t]` command.

Do the following from *normal* mode:

```
:.,+2y|new|put!
```

It may be helpful to know that you can also directly write those three lines to a file with:

```
:.,+2w filename
```

Comment: > `:.,+2|`. Guess you meant `:.,+2y|`.

Comment: Yes. That's not what my fingers meant, somehow. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use one of the following to copy from the clipboard in Vim:

<kbd>"</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>

<kbd>"</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>INSERT</kbd>

Which one you use depends on your environment.

If you're using gVim or MacVim, you'll want `"+p`

If you're using Vim from the command line, you'll want `"*p`

If you're in insert mode or ex mode (I think) you use <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>INSERT</kbd>

By insert I mean the key over by <kbd>HOME</kbd>, <kbd>PAGE UP</kbd>, and <kbd>DELETE</kbd>

Explanation:

- `"` means you're going to specify a *register*
- there are 26 custom registers - 1 for each letter
- there are many other registers ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3997078/778118))
- `+` or `"` refers to the *unnamed buffer*, which represents the system clipboard
- `p` is the normal put command

More info on buffers:

If you want, you can store different text in different buffers.

To yank 3 lines to the buffer named *x* use this:

`"x3yy`

To paste the contents of the buffer named *y* above the cursor:

`"yP`

Comment: Thanks ....but what if i want to store specific lines in buffer...means lines form 3 to 8 ..then which command i should use...??

Comment: In gVim or MacVim you would use `"+y`.  In Vim from the command line you would use `"*y` (or other variations of the yank command).

Comment: I tend to use _marks_ when I yank text in Vim.  So, to answer your question specifically, I would go to line 3 then press `mx` to place a mark with the name _x_.  Then I would move to line 8 and use the following command (in gVim, for example): `"+y'x`.  In other words, yank all the text between _mark x_ and my cursor into the buffer named _x_.  After doing this you can paste your 5 lines into another program with _CONTROL-V_ or a menu command.  Or, all in one command: `3Gmx5j"+y'x`

Comment: I've never had that happen to me.  These commands should be used from command mode.  If you're in _ex mode_ I belive you want to use _SHIFT-INSERT_ to paste.

Comment: Re-read my answer... I've been editing it.  I mention a couple tricks for _ex mode_, too.

Comment: actually what i want to do is something like this...from ex mode....

While editing a file “file1” I want to read of the line nos. 10 to 20 from “file2”. How can I do this?

Comment: Swith to file2, copy the lines, then come back to file1 and paste them.  You can open file2 like this: `:e file2`.  You can switch between two files with _SHIFT-5_.  That's how I would do it.  I don't know how to do it from one file in ex mode.  That's not a workflow I've ever experienced.  I just store text in buffers and jump between files.

Comment: @TusharMishra - here's a pretty awesome answer with a bunch of info about registers: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3997078/778118

Comment: No problem... I hope some of that mumbo jumbo actually helped!

Answer (score 0):

**p** is just vi command, so it should be **pu** in ex instead.
or you can do with double quote, **"p** or **"np**. **n** is for the number in the register of buffer, **"2p** means the 2nd oldest yank you made.