# vi/vim editor, copy a block (not usual action)

Tags: vim, copy-paste, vi

In vi/vim editor, I need to copy a block. There are many ways, but one way is very quick.

1. label the first line by some way,
2. then label the end line by some way,
3. then put some command to copy the labeled lines.
4. then copy, may using 'p', but not sure.

Anybody know the commands (not yy or 10yy)?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Another option which may be easier to remember would be to place marks on the two lines with <kbd>m</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> and <kbd>m</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>, then run `:'a,'byank`.

Many different ways to accomplish this task, just offering another.

Comment: Yes. You can also yank into a specific register, eg. `:'a,'by a`.

Comment: I had never found a satisfactory and re-callable way of doing copy-paste in vi, but this solution is really topnotch. Also, I added this to .vimrc "command! P :'a,'byank" to allow the "P" key to function as a shortcut

Answer (score 166):

just use <kbd>V</kbd> to select lines or <kbd>v</kbd> to select chars or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> to select a block.

When the selection spans the area you'd like to copy just hit <kbd>y</kbd> and use <kbd>p</kbd> to paste it anywhere you like...

Comment: On a Windows PC, where `Ctrl+v` is pastig from the clipboard, you should use `Ctrl+q` to select a block

Comment: In macOS (at least) you need to enter VISUAL mode by `v` or `V` and then pressing `p`

Answer (score 132):

**[Their Documentation says:](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Copy,_cut_and_paste)**

**Cut and paste:**

1. Position the cursor where you want to begin cutting.
2. Press <kbd>v</kbd> to select characters (or uppercase <kbd>V</kbd> to select whole lines).
3. Move the cursor to the end of what you want to cut.
4. Press <kbd>d</kbd> to cut (or <kbd>y</kbd> to copy).
5. Move to where you would like to paste.
6. Press <kbd>P</kbd> to paste before the cursor, or <kbd>p</kbd> to paste after.

Copy and paste is performed with the same steps except for step 4 where you would press y instead of d:

<kbd>d</kbd> = `delete` = `cut`

<kbd>y</kbd> = `yank` = `copy`

Comment: OP asks about VI, your answer is about VIM, it does't help in VI.

Comment: @Kamil afaik the vi command on mac os starts vim and not vi. But anyways ops question was changed and now it includes vim. Thus i think Kaleems answer is ok. My first comment maybe helps someone who uses vi (what is a little bit different from vim) and wonders why this answer is not working for him.

Comment: @volkit That's not a feature of the operating system. Many Vim installs write this file at `/usr/bin/vi`: `exec vim "$@"`.  Users can check this with `vi --version`, and redirect it by editing `/usr/bin/vi`.

Answer (score 26):

I found the below command much more convenient. If you want to copy lines from 6 to 12 and paste from the current cursor position.

```
:6,12 co .
```

If you want to copy lines from 6 to 12 and paste from 100th line.

```
:6,12t100
```

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/8i6vbd/efficient_ways_of_copying_few_lines/

Answer (score 21):

It sounds like you want to place *marks* in the file.

<kbd>m</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> places a mark named *x* under the cursor

<kbd>y</kbd><kbd>'</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> yanks everything between the cursor's current position and the line containing *mark x*.

You can use <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> to simply move the cursor to the line with your mark.

You can use <kbd>`</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> (a back-tick) to move to the *exact location* of the mark.

---

One thing I do all the time is *yank everything between the cursor and mark x into the clipboard*.

You can do that like this:

<kbd>"</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>'</kbd><kbd>x</kbd>

NOTE: In some environments the clipboard buffer is represented by a `*` in stead of a `+`.

---

Similar questions with some good answers:

- [How to copy/paste text from vi to different applications](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10803436/778118)
- [How to paste from buffer in ex mode of vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13043986/778118)

Comment: Yeah marks are also a great way to do that, especially when your using pure vi, not vim...

Comment: I guess I'm long overdue to introduce `V` into my workflow.  Not sure why I don't use it...

Answer (score 13):

Keyboard shortcuts to that are:

1. For copy: Place cursor on starting of block and press **md**  and then goto end of block and press **y'd**. This will select the block to paste it press p
2. For cut: Place cursor on starting of block and press **ma**  and then goto end of block and press **d'a**. This will select the block to paste it press p

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as you do in vi, for example to yank lines from 3020 to the end, execute this command (write the block to a file):

:3020,$ w /tmp/yank

And to write this block in another line/file, go to the desired position and execute next command (insert file written before):

:r /tmp/yank

(Reminder: don't forget to remove file: /tmp/yank)