# Is there a way to insert the current search pattern into commandline?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, ag

After installing Ag.vim I've had a frequent need to copy a search from * or / into the command line to search across all files in a codebase.

Example use case:

1. I find a string of text `user_profile_uri` and use `*` to select it.
2. I press `:` to enter commandline line mode and enter `Ag` to start my file search

Is there a way to move or copy the text in my search cursor to the commandline without having to copy the initial text by manually?

Edit:

I'm close to figuring this out. `:registers` at the commandline will give me a list of registers and while in command mode I can use `Ctrl+R <registerkey>` to paste. However, the text I need looks like `\<user_profile_uri\>`

Comment: [How to paste text into Vim command line](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3997078)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a few ways to do this:

- Insert text from a register via `<c-r>{reg}`. In this case the search register, `/`. e.g. `<c-r>/`
- You can also insert the word under the cursor via `<c-r><c-w>`
- According to the documentation, [`:h AgFromSearch`](https://github.com/rking/ag.vim/blob/master/doc/ag.txt), you can do `:AgFromSearch` to run use the current search pattern

You can combine the `:AgFromSearch` and `*` to come up with a mapping to do this all in one step. Add the following to your `~/.vimrc` file:

```
nnoremap <leader>* *:AgFromSearch<cr>
```

Now you can use `<leader>*` to execute your search. The default `<leader>` is `\` so it would become `\*`. See `:h <Leader>` for more information.

For more help see:

```
:h c_ctrl-r
:h c_ctrl-r_ctrl-w
:h :AgFromSearch
:h <Leader>
:h registers
:h quote/
```

Comment: `:AgFromSearch` works! Thank you for such a detailed answer plus documentation references!