# mutt - index search on yanked text

Tags: mutt

I'm wondering if there is anyway to "search" or "limit" in the mutt index based on text yanked from either an "edit" or "page" mode.

I'm trying to build a macro for the index, that when pressed will limit the index to only mail from (`~f`) the `From: .*$` regex of the current item.

What this will help me to do is see the context of all the messages from a particular sender... it also helps when people accidentally "break threads" when they shouldn't.

I was hoping it would be similar to vim as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997078/how-to-paste-text-into-vim-command-line/3997110#3997110) and i could yank text from one area and then type `^R"` to paste back into the "search" or "limit" prompt.

I tried to make a macro to go into `edit` and then search for the from string, but i can't figure out how to paste it back into anything in the index...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an incomplete (and ugly) solution:

```
macro index O "|grep ^From | awk 'NR==1 {printf \"macro index Q l%s\",$2}' > /tmp/from;echo>>/tmp/from\n:source /tmp/from\nQ"
```

The `O` macro will extract the from address from the current message, and save a new macro definition to `/tmp/from`.

Then it will source that definition, and finally execute it.

Note: I'm having trouble adding newlines in the script (that's the reason for the `echo>>`, and the need for you to press enter at the end of the limit prompt. Will try to improve this.

Comment: This works great, thanks.  I've only changed the keybindings as the "Q" one is basically a throwaway (and not one that i'll ever use non-programatically).