# Mutt: Search/limit for messages from the same sender as currently selected message

Tags: mutt

When browsing my mail in mutt, I frequently want to look at all messages sent from a particular address. I can accomplish this by using `limit` and the search pattern: `~f somebody@example.com`.

I am trying to create a binding/macro from the index and/or pager view where I perform this search using the sender of the currently selected message. So something like this:

```
macro index "<limit>~f {sender-address-of-current-email}<enter>"
```

But I can't find any documentation on how to dynamically specify the sender of the current message in a search pattern. Is this possible?

Comment: I've [answered a similar request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28215755/605276) some time ago.

Comment: Thanks, yes I found your answer after posting this and am currently using a modified version of it. I guess I'll leave this question up anyway since hopefully there is a way to do this without needing to write a macro definition to a temp file.

Comment: @SeanMackesey Could you please post your answer so other users like myself can also benefit from it?