# In Vim how do I efficiently search and replace “ and ” with normal double quotes "

Tags: vim, find-replace

I got this code snippet from a tutorial and I would like to search and replace all occurrences of “ and ”, with normal double quote ". 
How can I efficiently do it in Vim?

```
{
  “runtime”: {
  “DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL”: “http://127.0.0.1:8100”
  },
  “import”: [
    “meteor-base@1.0.4”,
    “mongo@1.1.14”,
    “reactive-var@1.0.11”,
    “jquery@1.11.10”,
    “tracker@1.1.1”,
    “standard-minifier-css@1.3.2”,
    “standard-minifier-js@1.2.1”,
    “es5-shim@4.6.15”,
    “ecmascript@0.6.1”,
    “shell-server@0.2.1”
  ]
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: 1. Don't copy and paste, type. 2. You should probably report the issue to the persons in charge of the site on which you copied that snippet. 3. Just do a search/replace.

Answer (score 10):

In command-line mode you can use the following command to find each occurrence of `“` and `”` (in all lines), and replace them with `"`:

```
:%s/[“”]/"/g
```

To do this, (assuming you have the file open in vim):

1. Hit the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key to ensure you are `Normal` mode.
2. Hit <kbd>:</kbd> , you will notice `:` has appeared in box at the bottom of vim (that is the command line).
3. Type the rest of the command for finding each occurrence of `“` and `”` (in all lines), and replacing both with `"`.
4. Hit the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key.
5. You're done! The command line will say something like "made 56 substitutions on 13 lines".

Comment: the problem is, how do I type that kind of quotes, on the command line?

Comment: not sure what kind of keyboard you're using, but on a standard US keyboard or macbook pro those special double quotes ( “ ” ) doesn't exist.

Comment: Oh I am on a macbook too, but I am using Windows, you can use Alt + 0147 to type the curly quotation mark `“`. On OSX you can do something similar use this link: http://www.wikihow.com/Type-Symbols-Using-the-ALT-Key and scroll down to mac.

Comment: Sorry, but that's inefficient way, I was looking for a "Vim way" to solve the problem.

Comment: @JesusNana You can also yank (vim's way of copying) the curly quotation mark from the file itself into the command line but I will let you research that for yourself :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997078/how-to-paste-yanked-text-into-vim-command-line

Answer (score 10):

You can show the ASCII code of a character using `ga` in normal mode.

You can also input arbitrary UTF-8 code using <kbd>Ctrl+v</kbd>`uhhhh` for characters with code 0000 <= hhhh <= FFFF and <kbd>Ctrl+v</kbd>`Uhhhhhhhh` for the rest in insert mode and command mode so when starting in normal mode you need to type, similar to @shash678's answer:

`:%s/`<kbd>Ctrl+v</kbd>`u201c/"/g`

Comment: E486: Pattern not found: %s/<C-Vu201c>/"/g

Comment: <C-V> means Ctrl + v, you need to put `:%s/` then Ctrl + v (you will will be not able to see anything until you finish typing hex code), then `u` then `201c`, only after typing it all you will see your character `“`.

Comment: Got it thanks! Is there a way to do the search-replace on both quotes on one shot? something like %s/“|”/"/g

Comment: Yes, you can use regex-like search patterns, is this case `:%s/[”“]/"/g`

Comment: note for myself, press CTRL and v at the same time, type u201c, it will show as ", and type " as replacement

Answer (score 2):

To rephrase @mucka's answer:

`:%s/[`<kbd>Ctrl+v</kbd>`u201c`<kbd>Ctrl+v</kbd>`u201d]/"/g`

The above is similar the command below, but it allows you to retrieve the special chars using hex code with <kbd>Ctrl+v</kbd>:

```
:%s/[“”]/"/g
```

To show hex code any character in your file, move your cursor over that character in normal mode and execute `ga`.

Answer (score 0):

1. highlight the first smartquote before `runtime`, then hit <kbd>e</kbd> twice to select the other.
2. press <kbd>y</kbd> to yank. You now have a yank register with both types of smart quotes in it.
3. type `:%s/[` and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> and then <kbd>"</kbd> to paste the yanked text. Move backwards and remove the word `runtime` from the search, then move to the end and type `]/"/g` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>