# Surround Visual Text with more than 1 character

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

How would you surround the following text with **3 backticks** ```` ``` ```` using tpope's [Vim Surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround).

All I can is **1 backtick** using `` S` `` in visual mode:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define a custom surround:

(Insert following in your `.vimrc` or file specific config `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/markdown.vim` )

````
" Custom surrounds
let b:surround_{char2nr('c')} = "```\r```"
````

now *visual select* and `Sc` will give you desired surround.

Or use a snippet solution; for example using [Ultisnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips) define a snippet like so:

```
snippet code
\`\`\`${1}
${0:${VISUAL}}
\`\`\`
endsnippet
```

now visual select your desired lines then hit snippet expansion key ( mine is `Tab` ) type `code` and hit `Tab` again. that's it.

Comment: Nice one @dNitro - Will accept this as this is using Vim Surround. Though romainl answer was really good tool

Answer (score 10):

This is not what you asked but this can be done without surround:

````
(from visual mode)
c
```
<C-r>"
```
<Esc>
````

See `:help i_CTRL-R`.

1. `c`: Delete text and start insert. The deleted text is put in the unnamed register `"`.
2. Type the prefix characters.
3. Use `<C-r>"` to paste the content from the unnamed register.
4. Type the suffix characters.

Comment: Here is why I think it work - `:help registers` says **Unnamed register "" : Vim fills this register with text deleted with the "d", "c", "s", "x" commands or copied with the yank "y" command**. With c, the visually selected text is moved to the unnamed register. You type the prefix characters (triple backticks in the above example) and press `<C-r>"` to paste text from the unnamed register. Then add the suffix characters (again triple backticks in the example).

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997078/how-to-paste-yanked-text-into-the-vim-command-line

Answer (score 2):

Here another ultisnips solution.

```
snippet code "add backtics codes" w
`!v repeat(nr2char(96),3)` ${1:markdown}
${0:${VISUAL:type here}}
`!v repeat(nr2char(96),3)`
endsnippet
```

If you do not want "markdown" after the first line just get rid of it. I am showing this solution only to show how to avoid backslashing so much.