# How can i paste in escape mode of gvim

Tags: vim

I want to paste some word into command area of gvim. (in escape mode)

Say for example i have copied some search text from somewhere else

and now i want to search a huge string.

/howToPasteSomeHugeWord

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to paste yanked text into Vim command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997078/how-to-paste-yanked-text-into-vim-command-line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your pattern was copied from your browser it is placed on register `+`, so you can start searching by typing `/` then `Ctrl-r +`

If you copied some vim selection with `y` you can use: `/Ctrl-r 0`

You can also use any register in any mode, for example, you find a cool function and want to test it on vim you can do

```
:@+
```

The above command will execute wherever you have in your clipboard

If you want to copy your last command to clipboard you can do

```
:let @+ = @:
```