# VIM : word completion in command-line mode?

Tags: vim

When replacing a word with another in a buffer in command-line mode, `:%s/verylongword/newword/g`, is there a way to word-complete 'verylongword' somewhow from the contents of the buffer ?

Failing that, is there a way of copy-pasting 'verylongword' from the buffer when typing `:%s/verylongword/newword/g` ?

Comment: Yes it does, many thanks. Also, to paste text onto the command line, one can use CTRL-R, as per here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997078/how-to-paste-yanked-text-into-vim-command-line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Command-line window

While typing the command press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> to open the command-line window, see `:h c_CTRL-f`.

In the command-line window you can use all the usual vim commands to edit your command line.

---

### Paste from register

To paste from a buffer in command-line mode press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> followed by the register name.

For example press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> to paste from register `0` to paste the last yanked text.

See `:h c_CTRL-R` for more info.

---

### Object under cursor

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> also allows the following completions (quoted from vim help):

```
CTRL-R CTRL-F                           c_CTRL-R_CTRL-F c_<C-R>_<C-F>
CTRL-R CTRL-P                           c_CTRL-R_CTRL-P c_<C-R>_<C-P>
CTRL-R CTRL-W                           c_CTRL-R_CTRL-W c_<C-R>_<C-W>
CTRL-R CTRL-A                           c_CTRL-R_CTRL-A c_<C-R>_<C-A>
                Insert the object under the cursor:
                        CTRL-F  the Filename under the cursor
                        CTRL-P  the Filename under the cursor, expanded with
                                'path' as in gf
                        CTRL-W  the Word under the cursor
                        CTRL-A  the WORD under the cursor; see WORD
```