# How to copy text from Vim command line

Tags: vim

How to paste into vims command line was asked here  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997078/how-to-paste-yanked-text-into-vim-command-line). 
But how can I copy from the vim command line?

For example:

:python import sys; print(sys.executable)

Now I want to copy that line to the clipboard, for pasting it into an other editor.

Answer (score 2):

You can assign to a register the content of another register:

```
:let @+ = @:
```

Will assign in the system clipboard (`@+`) the last executed `:` command (`@:`).

However, this will become your last executed command. If you want to keep your `python` command as the last one, you can do the following:

First open the command history:

```
q:
```

Go on the line of the command you want to copy, then yank it in the system register (visually selects the whole line and yanks it):

```
"+yy
```

This will copy the whole line with the new line character at the end, if you just want the command without the new line, you can do:

```
v$h"+y
```

Finally, close the command history:

```
:q
```

Comment: Indeed, actually, what I wanted to achieve was to copy without the new line character, but it should then be `v$h"+`. I guess it depends on if the OP wants the command with a new line or not

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.

If you executed a command `:foo`, the command text line will be stored in register `:`, you can see it by `:echo @:`.

To have those value in clipboard, you just let `+` register have the same value.

So `:let @+=@:` or `call setreg('+',@:)` should help you.

Comment: But it is only the last command or? I can not scroll through history (arrow up) and then copy the one that I stoped at?

Comment: @newandlost one way is `q:` in normal mode  or `:ctrl-f` in command mode, to enter command window, you can yank/copy the previous command you want there

Answer (score 1):

`q:` open command-line window, it's filled with command-line history, you can copy via `"+yy`.