# How to append to the clipboard

Tags: vim, copy, append, clipboard

I know how to copy to the clipboard but how can I append to it?

I use this in my code:

```
let @+ =  my_expression
```

but that overwrites the clipboard.

I know that I can use the registers a-z to append to:

```
let @B = my_expression
```

which appends to register b, but what do I when I want to append to the clipboard?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

use:

```
let @+ = @+ . my_expression
```

or shorter:

```
let @+ .= my_expression
```

Reference: `:help :let.=`

Answer (score 11):

If you're not macro-ing, it's probably worth checking out [registers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1498026/1028230) as well.  `:help registers` was mind-blowing.

In an oversimplified nutshell, there are 26 additional "customizable clipboards", called registers, where you can store text, starting with `a` and going through `z`.

***You add text to a register in command mode by hitting `"`, naming the register (say `f`), and then typing the "motion" you want to select text.***

**NOTE:** We're using the named `f` register here b/c it's probably under your left index finger. That is, `f` is picked just b/c it's handy. You could replace `f` with `a` or `u` or `z` or whatever throughout if you wanted.

---

#### Copying with a register (cursor at [T]):

*Initial File State*

```
This is my first line.
[T]his is my second line. 
This is my third line.
```

Type `"fyy` in command mode to fill the register with one line (`yy`).

- Type `p` (* see below) to immediately paste it *from the default register*.
- Type `"f` to pick the `f` register and then `p` to paste from the `f` register directly. *Right now `f` and default as the same.*

So the result of typing `"fyyp` is exactly the same as having typed `yyp` with the default clipboard.

*Result*

```
This is my first line.
This is my second line. 
[T]his is my second line. 
This is my third line.
```

---

#### Appending to a register:

Use the capital letter to **append** to your existing register.

In the above example *after* pasting, press `j` to go down a line and then `"Fyy`.  Then type `p` to paste.  You've **appended** "This is my third line." to `f`'s contents.

*Result*

```
This is my first line.
This is my second line. 
This is my second line. 
This is my third line.
This is my second line. 
[T]his is my third line.
```

(Using a lower case `f` would have cleared out `f`'s contents and ended up with it only holding "This is my third line.")

> Why does `p` paste what's in register `f` immediately after you yanked into `f`?  Because your default register holds a pointer to the last selection, and apparently doesn't simply hold what you added to `f`, but pulls everything that's in `f` when you append.  It might be more expository to say, in the first case, "the result of typing `"fyy"fp` is exactly the same as having typed `yyp` with the default clipboard."
>
> But if you were now to `yy` a new line into the default register, you can hit `"f` to select the `f` register and then `p` to paste that previous value.

Comment: Though now [I've learned](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/how-to-copy-non-continuous-matched-lines-into-clipboard-tp1164018p1164021.html) *`@+` is the clipboard register, just in case.*

Comment: And the downvote is for?  Please comment so I can fix/integrate/address your implicit criticism.

Comment: OP asked for how to append to the system clipboard, which is different from appending to one of the named registers in VIM