# How would you do a cut and paste with this in VIM?

Tags: visual-studio, vim, viemu

Say you had this text:

```
SOMETHING_XXXXXXXXXXXXXX_ELSE
SOMETHING_XXXXXXXXXXXXXX_ELSE2
SOMETHING_XXXXXXXXXXXXXX_ELSE3
SOMETHING_XXXXXXXXXXXXXX_ELSE4
```

And you wanted to replace all `XXX..XXX` with this word:

```
HELLOWORLD
```

If I go into visual mode, then yank the word, how could I then replace the `XXX..XXX` in the 4 lines above using cut and paste?

If I try, what happens is the X gets into my 'clipboard' and then I'm stuck to just typing it out manually.

Comment: Is this a vim question or a visual studio question?

Comment: @Oded a [viemu](http://www.viemu.com/) question ;-) Not all vi[m] are equal.

Comment: @Oded viemu is a commercial port of vim to the VS environment.  In some cases, it behaves differently from vim, which is likely why the original poster thought to include it.

Comment: @pst - Fair enough. I would never use vim binding in VS... but to each his own.

Comment: You want to be able to paste the XXX from a register into :s command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if it will work in viemu, but in VIM you can do the following...

**Using Yank and Paste**

Yank the text to a specific register. Select the text in visual mode and use the command `"ay` to yank the text to the register `a`. Then when pasting call the command `"ap`, which pastes the contents of the `a` register.

**Using Normal Command**

But I would strongly prefer to use the normal command. Just select the lines

```
SOMETHING_XXXXXXXXXXXXXX_ELSE
SOMETHING_XXXXXXXXXXXXXX_ELSE2
SOMETHING_XXXXXXXXXXXXXX_ELSE3
SOMETHING_XXXXXXXXXXXXXX_ELSE4
```

using line visual mode (`<C-v>`) and then issue this command: `:'<,'>normal fXct_HELLOWORLD`. Then you'll have

```
SOMETHING_HELLOWORLD_ELSE
SOMETHING_HELLOWORLD_ELSE2
SOMETHING_HELLOWORLD_ELSE3
SOMETHING_HELLOWORLD_ELSE4
```

This means that it will run the command `fXct_HELLOWORLD` for each line. Let me explain the command:

- fX - moves the cursor until the first X;
- ct_ - deletes everything untill _ and puts you in insert mode;
- HELLOWORLD - the word which will substitute XXXXXXXXXXXXXX;

Comment: Thank you for the 'fX' and 'ct_'! Didn't know about those before.

Comment: @DavidPoole you can also use cf<char> if you want to change the character you are searching for.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to visually select all the code you want to replace and change it at once

> Ctrl+v 3jt_cHELLOWORLD[Esc]

*Note: it takes a couple of seconds for all lines to be updated*

Another way to be by creating a macro:

record macro:

> q10fXct_HELLOWORLD[esc]q

run macro on other lines:

> j@1j@1j@1

**q1** records a macro on character 1

**@1** replays macro

But search and replace is a good alternative for your question

Comment: This is why I prefer emacs ;-)

Comment: @pst Never tried emacs but I'm starting to think I should give them a shot.

Comment: It's just an old lisp dialect with some text editing function/display thrown in -- but it sounds like you are already on the [vi/vim learning curve plateu](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/steverowe/archive/2004/11/17/code-editor-learning-curves.aspx) so no reason to change ;-) Original comment for my "what is that supposed to do!?!?!" reaction. (I use enough vi/elvis to edit configuration files, and that's about it.)

Answer (score 0):

Highlight the four lines in visual mode, then

```
:'<,'>s/X\+/HELLOWORLD/g
```

Comment: Unless, of course, you wanted something even more automatic. :)

Comment: I don't want a search and replace solution, trying to learn this techniue using cut and paste if possible?

Answer (score 0):

Via this question: [How do I use vim registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497958/how-to-use-vim-registers) I found ^R in command mode will paste from a register.

For example, with XXXX highlighted then yanked into the " register:
:s/^R"/HELLOWORLD/g