# Duplicating line in Vim and appending few letters

Tags: vim, macros, text-editor, vi

I am editing a dictionary in a text file, containing Russian words - one word per line.

Some nouns are missing their derivatives, which are usually the same word appended by few more letters - in 6-7 variations as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

In Vim I would like to put the cursor in the first column and scroll down line by line. And when I recognize a noun, I'd like to press some (as few as possible!) keystrokes to take that word, copy it in separate lines and append the letters.

I can get rid of the duplicates by issuing `%sort u` later.

If I *could* run that command on the whole file it would be something like:

```
%s/\(.\+\)$/\1^M\1а^M\1ам^M\1ами^M\1ах^M\1е^M\1ном^M/
```

Do you please have an idea, how to create such a "macro" in Vim?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of ways that you can handle this. You can create a macro or you can create a map. Either can be done while running VIM. Either can be placed in another file (your `.vimrc`, for example, or a file with bindings specific to this project) and sourced when needed.

I will also give you a bit more advice with regular expressions: if you are writing something particularly complex, you can greatly decrease the number of `\`s needed by starting the regular expression with `\v` (i.e., `:s/\v([0-9a-f]+\s)/0x\1/g`).

**Creating a Macro in VIM**

You can start a macro in VIM by pressing <kbd>q</kbd> in Normal mode, followed by the key that you wish to use for the macro. You can then invoke the macro by pressing <kbd>@</kbd> followed by the macro's letter. Press <kbd>q</kbd> again in Normal mode to stop recording.

You can therefore enter this macro as follows (using the `q` register):

<kbd>q</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>:</kbd>`s/\(.\+\)$/\1\r\1а\r\1ам\r\1ами\r\1ах\r\1е\r\1ном\r/`<kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>

Then, when you are on a line and you want to run this command, enter <kbd>@</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> from Normal mode.

**Storing a macro in a file and sourcing it**

When you created a macro in the last step, what you were actually doing was setting the `q` register. You can check this by entering the `registers` in command mode. You can instead set this macro in your `.vimrc` file as follows and it will be available every time you start VIM.

1. Create the file you want to store this macro in (`:new`).
2. Add the following line to the file:

   `let @q=":s/\\(.\\+\\)$/\\1\\r\\1a\\r\\1b\\r\\1ам\\r\\1ами\\r\\1ах\\r\\1е\\r\\1ном\\r/^M"`

   (If you yank the line and paste it in VIM with <kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd><kbd>"</kbd>, there will be a proper `^M` character at the end of the line. You'll need to do some manual editing to make sure that it's inside the quotes. Alternatively, you can enter <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+M</kbd> to enter the ^M character.)
3. Save the file (`:w testmacro.vim`).
4. Source it (`:so %` or `:source %`).
5. Test your macro by typing <kbd>@</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> on one of the lines you'd like to do this to.

Later, you will be able to load this macro by running `:so testmacro.vim`.

**Create a Mapping**

You can instead create a mapping. The following mapping copies the last word in a given line, pastes it onto the following six lines, and then appends to each of the given lines.

`nnoremap <c-j> yy6pAа<esc>jAам<esc>jAами<esc>jAах<esc>jAе<esc>jAном<esc>j`

`n` at the beginning of "nnoremap" indicates that it only functions in Normal mode.
`noremap` means that this command won't engage in any recursive remapping (whereas with `nmap`, this could happen).
`<c-j>` maps to <kbd>Ctrl+J</kbd>
`yy6p` yanks the line and pastes it 6 times.
`Aa<esc>j` appends to the end of the current line, enters the text (in this case `a`), exits Insert mode, and moves down a line.

You can enter this command in VIM's command mode or you can store it in a file and load it with the `:source` command.

**Combining Registers with Mappings**

You can access a register in your mappings. This means that if you know that entering a given replacement regex will do what you want, you can save that in a register and then enter your command on the current line.

To do this, enter the following commands in a file and then source it:

```
nnoremap <c-i> :<c-r>f<cr>
let @f="s/\\(.\\+\\)$/\\1\\r\\1a\\r\\1b\\r\\1ам\\r\\1ами\\r\\1ах\\r\\1е\\r\\1ном\\r/^M"
```

Now you can enter <kbd>Ctrl+I</kbd> to run the replacement regex in register f on the current line.

Alternatively, dedicate a few registers to the purpose - let's say a-f.

```
nnoremap <c-l> yy6p$"apj"bpj"cpj"dpj"epj"fpj
let @a="a"
let @b="ам"
let @c="ами"
let @d="ax"
let @e="e"
let @f="ном
```

In this case, we're using the ability to press <kbd>"</kbd> and the name of a register before hitting a command that uses it, such as paste.

Comment: I can't see the point of the initial `qqq`. The final `q` will set the `q` register to the appropriate value, regardless of what is in the register at the start.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan, you're right. I had some advice from creating recursive macros stuck in my head.

Answer (score 4):

You can record macros by pressing `q` in the `escape` mode. For example,

1. position your cursor on the noun you want to edit.
2. press `qa` to start recording macro and store it in register `a` (other alphabet and digits may also be used for registers) .
3. do whatever general actions you want to do (copy line, paste, append letters, etc. as in you have tried to show in your search string).
4. once you are done with the changes, in `escape` mode press `q` again.

Your macro is now created in register `a`. Whenever, you want to repeat your key sequences, just press `@a`.

Note that you can do anything in `recording` mode, including any kinds of commands, insertions, cursor movements, and so on. For more information on macros and related options, check out Vim help `:h complex-repeat`.

Vim registers are shared as place holders for both macros and yanked test; this feature allows you to even save and edit your macros in a file. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1497958/567555) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a map solution - which copies the line into a buffer and then pastes using p.
 The A appends at the end of the line

```
  map <F2> 0dwpo<esc>pAa<enter><esc>pAam<enter><esc>pAax ...etc
```

Comment: I was going to propose similar, but yank and then paste all 8 and then do the appending:  `map t yy8pAa^[jAaM^[jAaMN`...  (you can get an escape by typing `control-v` and then `control-[` )

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is, when your cursor on a special word, and press something, vim will append different "suffixes" (I hope I used the right word, but you knew what I mean). You could go macro (`q`). However since you have already written the `:s` command, you could create a mapping using that command do the same, and it would be shorter.

in command line, you can get the word under cursor by pressing `<c-r><c-w>`. so you could try:

```
nnoremap <leader>z :s/<c-r><c-w>/& & &..../<cr>
```

I didn't write the `& & &...` part, since I don't know (never tried, I don't have vim under windows. I don't even have windows) if the line break `\n` could be used here under windows.  `&` means the whole matched part, which in this case is the word under your cursor.

So you just move your cursor to the word, type `<leader>z`, vim will do the job for you. (if the replacement part is correct :) ).