# How to copy text in Emacs Evil-Mode without overwriting the clipboard?

Tags: vim, emacs, copy-paste, evil-mode

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497958/how-to-use-vim-registers) described how to do it in Vim, where one prefixes their copy command with `"` + `<register name>` (ie `k`). How can I do this in Emacs Evil-Mode?

For example, I tried the following:

- `yy` - copy first line to clipboard
- `jjj` - move to some new line
- `"kyy` - copy second line to register `k`
- Move to my new region
- `p` - paste first line
- `"kp` - paste second line

However, at `p`, Emacs pastes my second line, as if the register was ignored and copied directly to the clipboard. Any suggestions on how to use Vim-like registers? If not, any suggestions on how to copy and paste multiple regions in Evil-Mode?

Comment: does `:registers` show anything in register `k` after you typed `"ky`?

Comment: Yes, register `k` stores my copied text, but my clipboard is also replaced with the copy text. How can I retain the clipboard contents when copying in evil-mode?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think setting this value will do it:

```
(setq x-select-enable-clipboard nil)
```

Using evil (in spacemacs), `"+y` still copies to clipboard, so I think that should work.

---

If not, [this blog post](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20150313145313/http://www.codejury.com/bypassing-the-clipboard-in-emacs-evil-mode/) describes a more verbose method: Write handlers for all ways you can delete to avoid touching the clipboard and rebind keys to use these handlers.

Comment: Wow, that blogpost is exactly what I've needed. It solves my problem perfectly! And the code is very clean and modular ;-)

Comment: This does not work in emacs started as "emacs -nw", i.e, working in the terminal. Can you suggest some alternative which would work in the terminal too?

Comment: @enitihas: I don't know. I don't see how `yy` in terminal could be very different from windowed. You'll probably need to ask a new question specific to the terminal (include a link to this question too!).

Comment: Hello @Lucas, I'm looking for the same thing, did you have the code to fix this? I'm asking you because now the link to that blogpost is broken. Thanks!

Comment: @ZzAntáres Sorry about the broken link! It's disappointing when that happens. But here is the code that should do the trick: https://github.com/LukeSwart/.emacs.d/blob/master/modes.el#L386-L479 Keep in touch if you have any issues!

Comment: Fixed link to use wayback machine.

Answer (score 2):

This is 100% the solution, if you're spacemacs and probably otherwise:

```
(fset 'evil-visual-update-x-selection 'ignore)
```

Credit to: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/15054/8377

Comment: This does not solve the problem outlined above. I think your answer is solving a different problem...

Answer (score 1):

It behaves similarly in vim. Numerical registers get overwritten no matter what register you intended to use. Running your examples in both Emacs (w/ evil of course) and Vim I get the `k` register filled up correctly and under register `0`, the most recent yank that happens to be the same as in `k`.

Comment: This is not to be regarded as the correct answer as I would also prefer to hear a fix to this small annoyance.

Comment: Check out idbrii 's answer above. His linked blog post seems to solve this issue perfectly.