# copy phase from vim coding to dev ++

Tags: vim, copy-paste, dev-c++

I coding a simple code in vim

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("%d\n", n);
    return 0;
}
```

and copy the same phase to the web.

and I copy again the same phase to dev c++ editor from the web.

[image]

Look! error stray '\240'!!

please look below I copy the same phase to here(stackoverflow.com)

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
????int n;
????scanf("%d", &n);
????printf("%d\n", n);
????return 0;
}
```

I figure out character '?' is add up.
I can not see character '?' in dev c++ editor.
However, It is very difficultly to delete because I cannot see '?' in dev c++ edtor.

I have to copy phase some code to web. and somebody have to copy phase the same code to dev c++. I guess the someone will compile and will error stray '\240'.

I like to use vim. can some know how not to add '?'('?' is '\240') up using vim?

Comment: How are you copying it out of vim? Using your os copy copy or are you placing it on the system pasteboard  from inside vim

Comment: @Doon, it's kind of homework. my code in mac -> copy phase -> "web page". and someone copy the phase on "web page" to someone's windows computer(dev c++).

Comment: updated my answer to remove the windowisms and replace them with MacOS keys ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to copy to the primary system clipboard you can yank into `*`.  Then you should be able to paste it using the normal `cmd-v`  into websites, or other text fields.   If you are just selecting all the txt and hitting `cmd-c` to copy it, it appears that you are getting the control chars as well the text.  I have the following in my vimrc to make cutting and pasting between vim and the system clipboard way easier.

```
" Yank text to the OS X clipboard
noremap <leader>y "*y
noremap <leader>d "*d
noremap <leader>p :set paste<CR>:put  *<CR>:set nopaste<CR>
```

so this way I can select what I want, and hit leader y and then paste it wherever it needs to go, and not have to worry about touching the rodent (mouse).  The `Leader p` is handy so that vim doesn't reformat your text on paste (Which happens a lot with code and `cmd-v`).

Comment: "*y will yank to * which is the system clipboard on OS X.  So you  can then use cmd-v to paste into something that isn't vim.  And it won't grab any control chars. Especially if you are running vim in a terminal.

Comment: What part isn't working.? The yanking to the system clipboard or are you still getting control chars?

Comment: the yanking to the system clipboard.

Comment: And you are selecting your text, then hitting "*y to put it on the system clipboard.  Odd. What version of vim are you using ? It is possible that it has been compiled without access to the system clipboard.

Comment: version 7.4, not working yy, y1y,  y2y, ...what does it mean "*y

Comment: Select what you want to copy,  then hit the keys " then * then y in that order.  Hence the reason I map them to leader y (my leader is space) so I can select and hit space y and it copies.

Comment: how well do you know vi? . a quite simple hack would be to just cat the file, and then cut and paste the part that you want, using normal os keys.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497958/how-do-i-use-vim-registers for more info on registers,  on osx `*` and `+` are the same.

Comment: `yy`, yanks to the unnamed register.  `"*yy` will yank the * register which is the system clipboard.  Read the link about registers I think i will help?

Comment: it's not about what yank or not yank, it's about copy-phase(cmd+v). what I yank is not what i copy-phase.

Comment: Because you need to yank it to a specific register.  If you yank to the * or + register that puts it on the system clipboard and makes it available to be pasted.